# How to have a mix of the latest contents with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having multiple different data sources and on a website. I'm displaying items in the descending date order (showing the latest first). All data sources can be described as a separate category. Let's say I have sources for Cars, Boats, Motorbikes. The problem is that when new Cars being added to my index, my homepage will be filled with Cars only. However, I still want the users to see Cars, Boats, Motorbikes as well.

Is there query that can return a mix of multiple categories **without specifying any category**? I have thousands of categories, I cannot add multiple conditions for each. It is like saying: I want the latest contents that are mostly distinct in categories (each item can have tens of categories as well).

Comment: what about https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/search-aggregations-bucket-diversified-sampler-aggregation.html?

Comment: That can work, couldn't find it before in the docs. I'l try it as soon as I got some time.